# How to sort a collection(like top 20) by count of related collection filtered by related colection's attribute?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    autor:              {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true},
    texto:              {type: String},
    likes:              [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'like'}],

});

var likeSchema = new Schema({
    user:       {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: true},
    post:       {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'post', required: true},
    _created_at:{type: Date},
});
```

I want all documents from collection 'post' sorted by the count of relationship 'likes' that were created in the last 24 hours(could be other periods) using the attr '_created_at'.

F.I. "Posts that received the most likes in the past 24 hours"

I heard that using aggregate was a good idea but I lack of experience with it and don't exacly know what pipeline should I go for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the post ID is enough for you, you can use:

```
db.like.aggregate([
    //filter the likes creation dates as you need
    { $match  : { _created_at: { $gte: ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z") } } },
    //group by post ID and count them
    { $group  : { _id: "$post", count: {$sum: 1} } },
    //sort by count, descending
    { $sort   : { count : -1 } },
    //limit the results in 20 maximum (if you need only the top 20)
    { $limit  : 20 }
])
```

This will return a list like this:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5774826af4a48761f2ff0da1"),
    "count" : 5
}, ...]
```

However, if you need to get the complete post in the same query, you will need MongoDB v.3.2 ($lookup is not available before that). And the query would be:

```
db.like.aggregate([
    //filter the likes creation dates as you need
    { $match  : { _created_at: { $gte: ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z") } } },
    //group by post ID and count them
    { $group  : { _id: "$post", count: {$sum: 1} } },
    //sort by count, descending
    { $sort   : { count : -1 } },
    //limit the results in 20 maximum (if you need only the top 20)
    { $limit  : 20 },
    //bring the complete post from the related collection
    { $lookup : { from: "post", localField: "_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "post" } },
    //deconstructs the array created by lookup to a single object
    { $unwind : "$post" },
    //remove the ID and include on the complete post and count (this step is optional)
    { $project: { _id: 0, post: true, count: true } }
])
```

That will return a list like this:

```
[{
    "count" : 5,
    "post" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5774826af4a48761f2ff0da1"),
        "autor" : ObjectId("577480bcf4a48761f2ff0d92"),
        "texto" : "texto06",
        "likes" : [
            ObjectId("5774882df4a48761f2ff0db9"),
            ObjectId("5774882df4a48761f2ff0dba"),
            ObjectId("5774882df4a48761f2ff0dbb"),
            ObjectId("5774882df4a48761f2ff0dbc"),
            ObjectId("5774882df4a48761f2ff0dbd")
        ]
    }
}, ...]
```

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Hope this helps!

Cheers!